# Access patches from recipe in a different layer

Tags: avr, yocto

I'm attempting to setup the avr toolchain while still utilizing the upstream binutils and gcc recipes. For example, the base recipe for binutils is in yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/. I have my custom avr-flavored recipe in yocto/meta-avr/recipes-devtools/avr-binutils/.

Inside the custom avr recipe are a few environment variable changes (TARGET_PREFIX, TARGET_SYS, etc), and then a "require recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.23.2.bb". This lets me depend on the upstream binutils recipe without having to replicate everything manually.

Now, the problem I'm having is that the upstream recipe has a bunch of patches that get applied. I can't figure out how to have my custom recipe point to a filepath outside its layer so I can use the patches that already exist. I've tried using FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a `.bbappend` file, which will inherit the existing recipe and allow you to override some parts of it.